# Declare an overloadable abstract method?

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class, class-design

I'm creating a java class library, and I'm trying to implement a factory pattern to assist the creation of 'Booking' objects. I created an interface, IBookingFactory, which declares a method, createBooking, that takes a number of parameters.

My problem is, I wan't the classes that implement this interface to be able to pass different parameters to the method.

The classes that implement the interface are a GuestBookingFactory and a CustomerBookingFactory. The customer booking accepts a ticket, customer and quantity, the guest booking accepts a ticket, quantity, and String email & address.

Any tips on how to design this? I know I cannot overload a method declared in an interface, and so I was wandering how else can I think about this problem?

```
    public interface IBookingFactory {
        public Booking createBooking(Ticket ticket, Customer customer, Integer quantity);
    }

    public class CustomerBookingFactory implements IBookingFactory {

        @Override
        public CustomerBooking createBooking(Ticket ticket, Customer customer, Integer quantity) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }

    }

    public class GuestBookingFactory implements IBookingFactory {

        @Override
        public Booking createBooking(Ticket ticket, Integer quantity, String email,
        String address, String postcode) {

            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can overload a method declared in an interface.

Comment: How? I get an error saying that the method doesn't override or implement a method from a return type - I presumed this is because I've declared the method in the interface as taking a ticket, customer and quantity, and now i'm trying to implement it for a guest I want to 'overload' the method and pass different parameters.

Comment: Yes you can have any number of overloaded methods even in an interface. You just need to provide implementation for all declarations

Comment: @Charlie You need to show us your code.

Comment: Code added. The last class throws the error.

Comment: @Charlie I'm not sure why you are using an interface at all. The two concrete methods have different parameters and different return types.

Comment: I guess my problem isn't whether or not a method can be overloaded in an interface, I would like to declare the method once - but be able to implement two versions of it for each concretion.. which take different parameters.

Comment: The return types aren't a problem - one will return a GuestBooking, the other a CustomerBooking (which are both types of Booking)

Comment: Yes this is your actual problem. And let me tell you that its possible only if parameters follow a hierarchy and number of parameters is same.

Comment: The idea behind an abstract method is that you can invoke the method on an instance of the interface without even knowing the concrete class of the object. You could never do that with your example because you need to know the concrete class in order to know what parameters to pass. An abstract method isn't really appropriate for this. There is no way to declare that every subclass must have some method with a particular name (but unspecified parameter list).

Comment: OK thanks Paul - just what I was looking for. I'll remove the abstraction of the method and leave them as separate concrete classes.

Comment: Charlie, there's no reason not to have a single factory class with two different methods to create a Booking, one being the `CustomerBooking createBooking(Ticket ticket, Customer customer, int quantity)` and the other one `GuestBooking createBooking(Ticket ticket, Integer quantity, String email, String address, String postcode)`.